# Как узнать значение битов в массиве байт?

Tags: java, битовые-операции, byte

Есть массив байт `byte[10]`. В одном из элементов массива находится байт, биты которого содержат информацию об успешном/неудачном исходе операции. Другими словами, требуется определить второй бит (если считать слева) в байте. Как это можно сделать? С побитовыми операция знаком слабо, но после ознакомления с этой темой, всё равно не нашёл ответа на свой вопрос. Подскажите как это сделать или дайте пример

Answer (score 7):

```
byte b;

//blah-blah

if((b & 2) > 0)
   System.out.println("Bingo! Operation is successful");
else
   System.out.println("Sorry, operation failed...");
```

Comment: Студия будет ругаться `operator '&' cannot be applied to byte, boolean`

Comment: `if((b & 2) > 0)`

Comment: Я в таких случаях всегда говорю - я не компилятор, я даю только идею

Answer (score 6):

Как проверить бит в байте побитовой операцией уже написал @Barmaley.

Для упрощения побитовых операций можно использовать [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf(byte[])):

```
byte[] arr = new byte[10];
//инициализация arr
BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(arr);
if(bits.get(2)) { //2 - номер бита во всем массиве байтов
     //действие
}
```

Если остальные байты не разбираются можно передать массив из одного байта:

```
BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[]{ arr[x]});
```

Comment: `BitSet` нормальная тема, но только надо учитывать, что это крайне расточительный способ битовых операций. На каждый бит отводится `long`=64 бита. Обычно битовые операции применяются для экономии ресурсов, так что `BitSet` это такой программистский оксюморон, который надо применять с оглядкой.

Comment: @Barmaley да, `BitSet` заметно отстает по производительности, но разница в производительности будет ощутима только при больших нагрузках. `BitSet` улучшит читаемость кода, что особенно важно для начинающих. Если же при испытаниях обнаружится что `BitSet` «узкое» место, то оптимизация не составит труда.

Answer (score 3):

Хотя ответ default locale мне нравиться больше, так как он более читабельный неопытному юзеру, я опишу еще две возможности оперировать с побитовыми операциями.

1) 2 бит слева это 7 бит если считать со стороны [наименьшего значащаго бита](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit)(справа). Лучше практикой считаеться указывать именно положения бита слева.
Шифтим (сдвигаем) наш байт направо на 6 значений. Делаем "& 1" тем самым обнуляем все значения левее самого правого бита. Этот код дает нам значение нужного бита. [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145733/how-can-one-read-an-integer-bit-by-bit-in-java)

```
(my_byte >> 6) & 1;
```

2) Делаем логическую операцию "И" с маской 01000000 (что в десятичной форме равно 64) и проверяем равенство её нулю. Тем самым все значения кроме 7 бита будут аннулированы, а 7 оставит свое значение. Т.е. если он был ноль, то все чило будет 0, если было один, то число будет больше 0 (а именно 64).

```
(my_byte & 64) > 0;
```